How can I automatically check for a required field in the form, and a asterisk (*) in FormLabel in shadcn/ui, zod
Let's consider a schema written in zod.
import { z } from "zod";

const schema = z.object({
  name: z.string().min(2, {
    message: "Enter a valid name",
  }),
  website: z.string().min(2, {
    message: "Enter a valid website",
  }).optional(),
  phone: z.string().min(10, {
    message: "Enter a valid phone number",
  }),
});

I know that name and phone are required fields and website is a optional field.
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormLabel,
  FormDescription,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form";
import { z } from "zod";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";

export default function FormPage() {
  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof schema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
  });

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-8">
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="name"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Name</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input {...field} />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormDescription>Enter your name.</FormDescription>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            <FormField
              control={form2.control}
              name="website"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Website</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input {...field} />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormDescription>Enter your website.</FormDescription>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="phone"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Phone Number</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input {...field} />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormDescription>Enter your phone number.</FormDescription>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
        <Button type="submit" className="w-full mt-6">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </form>
    </Form>
  );
}

The issue at hand is, in the UI part I don't see any asterisk (*) to show it required as important.

Only when I click on submit it shows as required, because it was not filled

What can I do that via schema the required information is properly inferred and it shows the mark ?
I tried modifying the form.tsx of shadcn to get the mark but it would require me to explicitly mention it is a required field
const FormLabel = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof LabelPrimitive.Root>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof LabelPrimitive.Root> & {
    required?: boolean;
  }
>(({ className, required, ...props }, ref) => {
  const { error, formItemId } = useFormField();

  return (
    <Label
      ref={ref}
      className={cn(
        error && "text-destructive",
        required && 'after:ml-0.5 after:text-destructive after:content-["*"]',
        className
      )}
      htmlFor={formItemId}
      {...props}
    />
  );
});
FormLabel.displayName = "FormLabel";

The modified code part
 <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-8">
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="name"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel required>Name</FormLabel> {/* Added required here  */}
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input {...field} />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormDescription>Enter your name.</FormDescription>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            <FormField
              control={form2.control}
              name="website"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Website</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input {...field} />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormDescription>Enter your website.</FormDescription>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="phone"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel required>Phone Number</FormLabel> {/* Added required here  */}
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input {...field} />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormDescription>Enter your phone number.</FormDescription>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
        <Button type="submit" className="w-full mt-6">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </form>


I was trying to find a way where I don't have to pass required in the FormLabel and it will detect automatically which is a required field by Zod and Mark it as required via asterisk.
Complete form.tsx take from shadcn/ui forms
import * as React from "react";
import * as LabelPrimitive from "@radix-ui/react-label";
import { Slot } from "@radix-ui/react-slot";
import {
  Controller,
  ControllerProps,
  FieldPath,
  FieldValues,
  FormProvider,
  useFormContext,
} from "react-hook-form";

import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import { Label } from "@/components/ui/label";

const Form = FormProvider;

type FormFieldContextValue<
  TFieldValues extends FieldValues = FieldValues,
  TName extends FieldPath<TFieldValues> = FieldPath<TFieldValues>
> = {
  name: TName;
};

const FormFieldContext = React.createContext<FormFieldContextValue>(
  {} as FormFieldContextValue
);

const FormField = <
  TFieldValues extends FieldValues = FieldValues,
  TName extends FieldPath<TFieldValues> = FieldPath<TFieldValues>
>({
  ...props
}: ControllerProps<TFieldValues, TName>) => {
  return (
    <FormFieldContext.Provider value={{ name: props.name }}>
      <Controller {...props} />
    </FormFieldContext.Provider>
  );
};

const useFormField = () => {
  const fieldContext = React.useContext(FormFieldContext);
  const itemContext = React.useContext(FormItemContext);
  const { getFieldState, formState } = useFormContext();

  const fieldState = getFieldState(fieldContext.name, formState);

  if (!fieldContext) {
    throw new Error("useFormField should be used within <FormField>");
  }

  const { id } = itemContext;

  return {
    id,
    name: fieldContext.name,
    formItemId: `${id}-form-item`,
    formDescriptionId: `${id}-form-item-description`,
    formMessageId: `${id}-form-item-message`,
    ...fieldState,
  };
};

type FormItemContextValue = {
  id: string;
};

const FormItemContext = React.createContext<FormItemContextValue>(
  {} as FormItemContextValue
);

const FormItem = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLDivElement,
  React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => {
  const id = React.useId();

  return (
    <FormItemContext.Provider value={{ id }}>
      <div ref={ref} className={cn("space-y-2", className)} {...props} />
    </FormItemContext.Provider>
  );
});
FormItem.displayName = "FormItem";

const FormLabel = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof LabelPrimitive.Root>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof LabelPrimitive.Root> & {
    required?: boolean;
  }
>(({ className, required, ...props }, ref) => {
  const { error, formItemId } = useFormField();

  return (
    <Label
      ref={ref}
      className={cn(
        error && "text-destructive",
        required && 'after:ml-0.5 after:text-destructive after:content-["*"]',
        className
      )}
      htmlFor={formItemId}
      {...props}
    />
  );
});
FormLabel.displayName = "FormLabel";

const FormControl = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof Slot>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof Slot>
>(({ ...props }, ref) => {
  const { error, formItemId, formDescriptionId, formMessageId } =
    useFormField();

  return (
    <Slot
      ref={ref}
      id={formItemId}
      aria-describedby={
        !error
          ? `${formDescriptionId}`
          : `${formDescriptionId} ${formMessageId}`
      }
      aria-invalid={!!error}
      {...props}
    />
  );
});
FormControl.displayName = "FormControl";

const FormDescription = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLParagraphElement,
  React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLParagraphElement>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => {
  const { formDescriptionId } = useFormField();

  return (
    <p
      ref={ref}
      id={formDescriptionId}
      className={cn("text-sm text-muted-foreground", className)}
      {...props}
    />
  );
});
FormDescription.displayName = "FormDescription";

const FormMessage = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLParagraphElement,
  React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLParagraphElement>
>(({ className, children, ...props }, ref) => {
  const { error, formMessageId } = useFormField();
  const body = error ? String(error?.message) : children;

  if (!body) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <p
      ref={ref}
      id={formMessageId}
      className={cn("text-sm font-medium text-destructive", className)}
      {...props}
    >
      {body}
    </p>
  );
});
FormMessage.displayName = "FormMessage";

export {
  useFormField,
  Form,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormControl,
  FormDescription,
  FormMessage,
  FormField,
};


Here is exactly what you need - https://substack.com/profile/200733325-runespoor-engineering/note/c-66073144
Just put zod schema inside the context over the Form and use this hook inside  FormLabel
UPD:
The solution is pretty similar:

To know that zod field is optional, use <zodField> instanseof ZodOptional construction.
To access object field, use <zodObject>.shape.<field>
To access object field if object is an array element, use <zodArray>._def.type.shape.<field>

To make it elegant, use the provided code snippet. Of course, you could provide the schema using react context. Other required stuff already exists inside generated by Shadcn file (ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/form).
Important: the result might be unexpected with difficult schemas that include recursions or conditions.

Create useFieldOptionalityCheck hook:

import get from 'lodash/get';
import { useMemo } from 'react';
import { ZodOptional, ZodSchema } from 'zod';

const TEMPORARY_REPLACEMENT_PLACEHOLDER = '__PLACEHOLDER__';
const ZOD_OBJECT_FIELD_PATH = '.shape.';
const ZOD_ARRAY_FIELD_PATH = '._def.type';

export const generateZodFieldPath = (fieldName: string) => {
  return fieldName
    .replaceAll(/\.\d+/g, TEMPORARY_REPLACEMENT_PLACEHOLDER)
    .replaceAll(/\./g, ZOD_OBJECT_FIELD_PATH)
    .replaceAll(new RegExp(TEMPORARY_REPLACEMENT_PLACEHOLDER, 'g'), ZOD_ARRAY_FIELD_PATH);
};

const handleNotFoundField = (fieldName: string) => {
  throw new Error(
    `Field ${fieldName} not found in schema. Make sure the field exists in the schema or do not 
    pass the schema inside the Form - in this case you could manually set the required property for FormLabel.`
  );
};

export type UseFieldOptionalityCheck = (fieldName: string, schema?: ZodSchema) => boolean | null;

export const useFieldOptionalityCheck: UseFieldOptionalityCheck = (fieldName, schema) => {
  return useMemo(() => {
    if (!schema) {
      return null;
    }
    const zodFieldPath = generateZodFieldPath(fieldName);
    // @ts-expect-error - form schema is always object
    const zodField = get(schema?.shape, zodFieldPath);
    if (!zodField) handleNotFoundField(fieldName);
    return zodField instanceof ZodOptional;
  }, [fieldName, schema]);
};


Pass zod schema to the context over the form.

Recieve zod schema inside the FormLabel component and use useFieldOptionalityCheck hook to know if the field related to this label is optional:


onst FormLabel = forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof LabelPrimitive.Root>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof LabelPrimitive.Root> & { isFieldRequired?: boolean }
>(({ children, className, isFieldRequired, ...props }, ref) => {
  const { name, error, formItemId } = useFormField();
  const { schema } = useContext(FormUtilsContext); // Context with zod schema
  const isFieldOptionalBasedOnSchema = useFieldOptionalityCheck(name, schema);

  return (
    <Label
      ref={ref}
      className={cn(error && 'text-destructive', className)}
      htmlFor={formItemId}
      {...props}
    >
      {children}
      <FormLabelOptionalitySuffix isOptional={isFieldOptionalBasedOnSchema} />
    </Label>
  );
});


Provide a brief code snippet or example instead of linking to an external resource.

@AliHemmati Hey, sure! The answer is upadted

I wanted to provide a complete implementation to the above answer.

Create useFieldOptionality hook:
import get from 'lodash/get';
import { useMemo } from 'react';
import { ZodOptional, ZodSchema } from 'zod';

const TEMPORARY_REPLACEMENT_PLACEHOLDER = '__PLACEHOLDER__';
const ZOD_OBJECT_FIELD_PATH = '.shape.';
const ZOD_ARRAY_FIELD_PATH = '._def.type';

export const generateZodFieldPath = (fieldName: string) => {
  return fieldName
    .replaceAll(/\.\d+/g, TEMPORARY_REPLACEMENT_PLACEHOLDER)
    .replaceAll(/\./g, ZOD_OBJECT_FIELD_PATH)
    .replaceAll(new RegExp(TEMPORARY_REPLACEMENT_PLACEHOLDER, 'g'), ZOD_ARRAY_FIELD_PATH);
};

const handleNotFoundField = (fieldName: string) => {
  throw new Error(
    `Field ${fieldName} not found in schema. Make sure the field exists in the schema or do not 
pass the schema inside the Form - in this case you could manually set the required property for FormLabel.`
  );
};

export type UseFieldOptionalityCheck = (fieldName: string, schema?: ZodSchema) => boolean | null;

export const useFieldOptionalityCheck: UseFieldOptionalityCheck = (fieldName, schema) => {
  return useMemo(() => {
    if (!schema) {
      return null;
    }
    const zodFieldPath = generateZodFieldPath(fieldName);
    // @ts-expect-error - form schema is always object
    const zodField = get(schema?.shape, zodFieldPath);
    if (!zodField) handleNotFoundField(fieldName);
    return zodField instanceof ZodOptional;
  }, [fieldName, schema]);
};


Pass zod schema as context. (I checked if it was possible to get the schema passed to the resolver but it was not possible)
const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof ProfileSchema>>({
context: ProfileSchema, // Schema passed as context to the form.
resolver: zodResolver(ProfileSchema),
defaultValues: {
  name: "",
  surname: "",
  email: "",
  // other values
},
values,

});

Inside form.tsx in FormLabel component, get the schema passed as context from the control object, field name from the FormFieldContext and pass it to the useFieldOptionalityCheck and render '*' based on the boolean returned by the hook.


form.tsx
  const FormLabel = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof LabelPrimitive.Root>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof LabelPrimitive.Root>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => {
  const { error, formItemId } = useFormField()
  const { name } = React.useContext(FormFieldContext); // Get field name from FormFieldContext
  const { control } = useFormContext()
  const schema = control._options.context._def.schema // Get the Schema from the control object
  const isFieldOptionalBasedOnSchema = useFieldOptionalityCheck(name, schema);
  return (
    <Label
      ref={ref}
      className={cn(error && "text-destructive", className)}
      htmlFor={formItemId}
      {...props}
    >
      {props.children}
      {!isFieldOptionalBasedOnSchema && '*'} // Show '*' if a field is required.
    </Label>
  )
})
FormLabel.displayName = "FormLabel"

